# How is a relation defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've read multiple ways of defining relations and was wondering what is generally accepted. One of these ways is as follows.

$xRy=C\iff C\subseteq A\times B$

and the cartesian product is defined as

$A\times B=D\iff (\forall x)(\forall y)((x,y)\in D\iff x\in A \land y\in B)$

Is this definition generally accepted or is there a more formal definition?

Comment: Why not just $A \times B = \{ (a,b) : a \in A, b \in B\}$, and a relation $R$ is a subset of $A \times B$, with the convention that $aRb$ is used to mean that $(a,b) \in R$? Why do you need something **more** formal?

Comment: I would argue that neither of your statements make a lot of sense as written. I don't know how to interpret $xRy = C$; are $x$ and $y$ fixed? Is $R$ the relation or is $C$?

Comment: No, x and y are free variables, and xRy is just the notation used to denote that the set is a relation with variables x and y (at least in the book I've been reading). Also, when I say more formal, I mean is there a relation that this definition couldn't encompass that could be given by a more general definition if such a definition even exists.

Comment: Also, the first statement is meant to be interpreted as any set, C, can only be a relation between the variables x and y if and only if C is a subset of AxB (whose free variables are x and y respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In set theory, *relations* are sets; thus "to be a relation" is a property of sets.

We define the *pair* $(x,y)$, for example with [Kuratowski's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition), and then we define the *cartesian product* of two sets $A$ and $B$ :

> $A \times B = \{ (x,y) \mid x \in A \text { and } y \in B \}$.

Finally, we define when a set is a (binary) relation :

> $\text {Rel}(A) \text { iff } \forall x \ [x \in A \to \exists y \exists z (x=(y,z))]$.

The symbol $xRy$ is an abbreviation for $(x,y) \in R$.

---

Due to the fact that $A \times B$ is the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ with $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, we have that :

> for every $C$, if $C \subseteq A \times B$, then $\text {Rel}(C)$.

Comment: So is the subset "definition" simply a derivable theorem from this definition then?

Comment: You do not need the " subset part" to define a relation in extension . You neeed the subset part when you want to specify that a relation A is a relation FROM a certain set A TO a certain set B. But knowing from which set and to which set is not necessary to assert that a set is a relation. For example, it is absolutely certain that the set { (1,1) , (a, 3), (6,9)} is a ( binary) relation, since it is a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: All I know about this relation is that  this relation is a subset of some cartesian product I do not know ( and need not to know). I can simply say that it is a cartesian product X cross Y , that  the domain set {1,a,6} is a subset of X and that the range {1,3,9} is a subset of Y.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest of all definitions I have seen is : " A relation is a set of ordered pairs".

Any set such that all its elements are ordered pairs is a relation.

In case the set is empty, the definition still holds vacuously, so the Empty set is a relation.

In what you wrote, C was supposed to be a ***set***. A set is not a sentence. But xRy is a ***sentence*** ( or an " open sentence"). So writing :

xRy = C

cannot mean anything, for a set cannot be the same object as a sentence.

What you could say is : A set C is a relation from A to B  defined by the sentence xRy iff

(1) C is a subset of  " A cross B" 
(2) any ordered pair (x,y) belongs to C <--> the sentence x R y is true.

---

(I) In traditional aristotelian philosophy, the term " relation " was one of the 10 " categories", that is, it was a kind of predicate. ***The specificity of relational statements was not recognized***: they were treated as ordinary Subject-Verb-Predicate statements.

So, the sentence " Socrates is Plato's master" was analyzed as : " being Plato's master" is a predicate ( an attribute) belonging to the subject " Socrates".

(II) This approach revealed unsatisfying, due to the fact that ***it does not allow to show the validity of reasonings involving relational statements.***

(1) Line A is parallel to B 
(2) Line B is parallel to C 
(3) Therefore?

If you treat " parallel to A " as a whole predicate and "parallel to C" as a whole predicate, you get, a reasoning of the form

(1) a is X
(2) b is Y

and you cannot conclude anything.

(III) So relations could not be treated as ordinary predicates. It was realized that they had to be considered as ***2-place predicates***. For example the true ( deep) structure of " A is parallel to B " is not " A is parallel-to-B" but

Parallel [( A, B) ]

in words: the ordered pair (A,B) satisfies ( makes true) the predicate " Parallel".

So " parallel" is in fact : __  Parallel __

And in general , a relation R is : ____ R  ____

(IV) Following Frege, one can say that  **_R _** is an "open sentence". For any pair (x,y) this open sentence takes a truth value ( true or false). In this way you can produce a fonction ( a truth function) taking as inputs ordered pairs ( x,y) and giving back truth values as outputs.

This leads to the " ***propositional function " definition*** of " relation" ( See Lipschutz, Schaum's outline of Set Theory, Chapter 6,  at Archive.org)

" A relation R consists of the following : 
(1) a set A 
(2) a set B
(3) an open sentence P (x,y) in which P(a,b) is either true or false for any ordered pair (a,b) belonging to the cartesian product A cross B. "

(V) The preceding approach was still ***intensional***, it involved concepts ( " intensions" in traditional philosophy) , for the "open sentence" involved in the definition of the relation could be identified only by its ***meaning, its sense***.From the preceding point of view the relation " lady x is the ***wife*** of mister y " and the relation " lady x has as ***husband*** mister y " are not the same relation, because their open sentences do not involve the same concepts.

If mathematics wants to avoid this problem, it has  to define its objects in a purely ***extensional way***. They want to say that the two preceding relations are one and the same ( in spite of their purely " conceptual" difference). The only way to do this was to say that a relation R is nothing else than ***the set of all ordered pairs that are " selected" by its defining open sentence*** ( that is, nothing else than the ***" solution set"*** of this open sentence).

A motivation for this is geven below by Lipschutz

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the question is " is this set a relation?" you do not need the " subset" part of the definiiton. The definition you will use is : " a set is a relation iff it is a set of ordered pairs"

If the question is " is this set a relation from A to B?" you will need the " subset" part of the definition.

The definition you will use is : a set S is a relation from A to B iff

(1) it is a set of ordered pairs
(2) all these ordered pairs belong to the cartesian product A cross B,

which means , in brief, that S is a subset of the cartesian product A cross B.

---

Sometimes , instead of writing

set S = { x | x is a natural number and x is divisible by 2}

some authors write : S is the set such that

x belongs to S <--> x is a natural number and x is divisible by 2.

The same thing can be done for relations.

Instead of saying that

R = { (x,y) belonging to A cross B  | x = 3 y }

one can perfectly say that R is the set such that

(x,y) belongs to R <--> (x,y) belongs to A crosss B and x = 3y